# Capturing SSH Output in a variable in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting

I'm trying to SSH into another machine and caputre it's ip address and hostname into a variable.

However, the varaible seems to be empty when i echo it.

> I have tried out answers from other posts, but it didnt solve my problem. I'm not able to figure out as what the problem is.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/home/admin/Vishal/output.txt
input=host.txt

while IFS= read -r line
do 
echo "$line"
if [ $line = $HOSTNAME ]
then

ip=`hostname -i`
domain=`hostname -A`
host=`hostname`
sudo echo $ip $domain $line localhost >> $FILE

else
output=$(ssh -i -t admin@$line  << "ENDSSH"

ip2=`hostname -i`
domain2=`hostname -A`
host2=`hostname`
ENDSSH
)
echo $output
fi

done <"$input"
```

The **input** file contains a list of hostnames

The variable **FILE** contains the path of the file where the results are to be stored.

The varaible **output** is the one in which i want to store the results.

Note: The script works for first part of the if where ssh isnt required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ony this command is relevant for your quesion:

```
output=$(ssh -i -t admin@$line  << "ENDSSH"

ip2=`hostname -i`
domain2=`hostname -A`
host2=`hostname`
ENDSSH
)
```

The command sets some variables, but doesn't produce any output, so it's expected that `output` does't contain your values.

If you really want three lines with `hostname` related values, then something simple like this should work

```
output=$(ssh admin@$line "hostname -i; hostname -A; hostname")
```

Comment: how do i get the output? can you kindly elaborate?